# ReactJS - Autosave with multiple inputs - best practices

Tags: reactjs, autosave, debouncing

The goal I want to achieve is to implement the autosave function without hurting the performance (useless rerenders etc).
Ideally, when the autosave will happen, the state will also be updated.
I created an example component with 3 inputs, in this example the component rerenders on every keystroke. I also have a useEffect hook in which I'm looking for data changes and then I save them after 1sec.
The ChildComponent is used to preview the input data.

```
function App(props) {
  
  const timer = React.useRef(null);  
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(props.inputData);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    clearTimeout(timer.current)
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Saving call...", data)
    }, 1000)
  }, [data])

  const inputChangeHandler = (e, type) => {
    if (type === "first") {
      setData({ ...data, first: e.target.value })
    } else if (type === "second") {
      setData({ ...data, second: e.target.value })
    } else if (type === "third") {
      setData({ ...data, third: e.target.value })
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="inputFields">
        <input 
          defaultValue={data.first} 
          type="text" 
          onChange={(e) => inputChangeHandler(e, "first")} 
        />
        <input 
          defaultValue={data.second} 
          type="text" 
          onChange={(e) => inputChangeHandler(e, "second")} 
        />
        <input 
          defaultValue={data.third} 
          type="text" 
          onChange={(e) => inputChangeHandler(e, "third")} 
        />
      </div>
      <ChildComponent data={data} />
    </>
  )
}
```

I've read about debounce but my implementation didn't work. Has anyone run into the same problem?

Below is my debounce implementation using lodash:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Saving call...", data)
}, [data])

const delayedSave = React.useCallback(_.debounce(value => setData(value), 1000), []);

const inputChangeHandler = (e, type) => {
  if (type === "first") {
    let obj = { ...data };
    obj.first = e.target.value;
    delayedSave(obj)
  } else if (type === "second") {
    let obj = { ...data };
    obj.second = e.target.value;
    delayedSave(obj)
  } else if (type === "third") {
    let obj = { ...data };
    obj.third = e.target.value;
    delayedSave(obj)
  }
}
```

The problem with this one is that if a user types immediately (before the 1sec delay) from the first input to the second it only saves the last user input.

Comment: "Didn't work" in what way? Do you get errors?

Comment: @GuyIncognito no errors,I was typing immediately from the first input to the second and waiting for the autosave, and it only saved the last one.

Comment: Because the ```setData``` is asynchronous, the data would not be updated immediately.

Comment: Have you considered implementing debounce using lodash?

Comment: Yes @GlenCarpenter, my implementation was with lodash. I will try to recreate it in the above example and I will edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your implementation is that the timer is set in a closure (in `useEffect`) using the `data` your component had *before* the timer starts. You should start the timer once the `data` (or the `newData` in my implementation proposal) is changed. Something like:

```
function App(props) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(props.inputData);
  const { current } = React.useRef({ data, timer: null });

  const inputChangeHandler = (e, type) => {
    current.data = { ...current.data, [type]: e.target.value };

    if(current.timer) clearTimeout(current.timer);

    current.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      current.timer = null;
      setData(current.data);
      console.log("Saving...", current.data);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input defaultValue={data.first} type="text" onChange={(e) => inputChangeHandler(e, "first")} />
      <input defaultValue={data.second} type="text" onChange={(e) => inputChangeHandler(e, "second")} />
      <input defaultValue={data.third} type="text" onChange={(e) => inputChangeHandler(e, "third")} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me @Daniele, the only problem with this one is that the component re-renders at every keystroke and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Just remove the `setData(newData)` from `inputChangeHandler` @Christakitos

Comment: In the code above you're using `newData={...data etc}`, if you remove the setData every time you type in a different field it will get the initial values again. This could be fixed with refs, but the thing is that I also need the state to update. I'm sorry, I didn't specified that in my description.

Comment: I'm not sure that with the code above fields keeps theyr original values @Christakitos , are you sure your code has not `value={data.first}` in the three `<input>` tags? If that's the case I suggest you to read about [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and the included link about controlled Vs uncontrolled input; it's in the nature of a controlled component to re-render at each key stroke

Comment: My inputs have `defaultValue = {data.first}` and so on, to be specific,  but other than that if you change the state on every kerystroke, doesn't it mean that the component will re-render? I'm wondering if it's possible to update the state in the timeout function, every 1s after typing for example.

Comment: Yes it's possible @Christakitos , but if you update the state the component re-render, that's how React.js works... to let me understand what *actually* happen in your code it could be a good idea if you update the code in your question as your real code.

Comment: I updated my code above @Daniele, this is exactly what is happening in my actual code. I have a component which contains 2 or more inputs whose default values come from the parent component. This component has a child component which acts like a preview for the input data. I am trying to autosave that data with a 1s delay and also update the state in this delay without rerendering on every keystroke.

Comment: Please try my updated answer @Christakitos ; please keep in mind that on state update (after the 1s timeout) React.js re-renders the component.

Comment: I was using this solution before @Daniele and the main problem with this one is that if you type on the first input and immediately to the second (before the 1s delay) your updated state contains only the last input data.
I used refs to bypass that (when I saved the second input state I also updated the state for the other 2 with their ref.current.value) but I don't really like the ref solution,

Comment: You are right @Christakitos , I didn't considered the case in the "main problem". Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you @Daniele, I appreciate your input. I liked your idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the timer id to null inside the timer handler.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    clearTimeout(timer.current)
    timer.current = setTimeout(()=>{
      timer.current = null;
      console.log("Saving...",data)
    },1000)
},[data])
```

Comment: Could you explain your thinking on this @Beyond? Isn't the clearTimeout enough?